# Beginner: How Can I make COUNT Function not be recurring with Join? MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm a beginner programmer and have struggled with what I believe is a simple question about using the COUNT function. I have tables, and I need to be able to calculate the number of tickets available for an event. The requested_event table has the event capacity. The ticket table has the tickets sold.

```
SELECT a.BoughtTickets, b.event_capacity, b.event_id
FROM
(SELECT 
COUNT(*)  AS BoughtTickets 
FROM ticket
GROUP BY event_id

) a
JOIN
(SELECT 
event_capacity,
event_id
FROM requested_event JOIN approved_event
ON requested_event.reservation_id = approved_event.reservation_id
) b
```

I've tried that but it comes back as

```
    Bought Tickets  event_capacity  event_id
3                   150             1
1                   150             1
3                   1500            2
1                   1500            2
```

When in fact there are only 3 tickets sold for event_id 1 and 1 ticket sold for event_id 2. Any Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I must commend this question; they tried something and is my reason to have upvoted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the JOIN condition.

```
SELECT a.BoughtTickets, b.event_capacity, b.event_id
FROM (SELECT event_id, COUNT(*)  AS BoughtTickets 
      FROM ticket
      GROUP BY event_id) a
JOIN (SELECT  event_capacity, event_id
      FROM requested_event 
      JOIN approved_event
        ON requested_event.reservation_id = approved_event.reservation_id ) b
 ON a.event_id = b.event_id  // here
```